# How to create the vision of a 2D camera looking at a 2D world

Tags: python, arrays, camera, 2d, perspective

In a 3D world, a camera looking out will create a 2D representation of what it sees, AKA a picture. Looking at a 3D cube would produce this 2D image:

[image: Cube image]

However, inside a 2D world, a camera looking out will create a 1D line of pixels that will represent what it sees.

The camera in this scene:

[image: Camera in Scene]

Would produce this 1D "image":
[image: 1D picture]

Think of the camera looking out. It would be unable to see all of the pink shape,  because most of it is obstructed be the red shape. It would only see the part that is unobstructed. Also, objects further away appear smaller.

**How can I create the view of a 2D camera looking out at a 2D world, creating a 1D image?**

I am looking for a method, preferably in Python, to accomplish this. I am trying to do this for some 2D creatures I am simulating. I want their input to be 1D array that represents their view of the world.

Comment: This is pretty broad for Stack Overflow. I gave an overview of the algorithm I'd try. At this level, it's not really Python-specific. But if you have trouble with any of the steps outlined, you'll have to ask a new, more specific question, preferably with your code examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a focal point at the creature. Draw a circle around it. Subdivide the circle for each pixel in your image resolution, and cast a ray from the focal point to the circle point and out into the world. Find the points of intersection between that ray and the world objects. Get the color of the closest one to set the color in the image at that pixel. Repeat for each pixel.

This gives a 360-degree perspective view, which might simplify things for a simulated creature. If you want a more directional view, just use an arc instead of a circle. 45 degrees seems reasonable.

Comment: Because you didn't mention it explicitly, I just want to add one phrase for further research in this direction: ray tracing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_(graphics)

Comment: Thanks! This method seems like it would work well. Plus, you can easily change the "resolution" of the creature's vision.